# Canvas vs CSS3 for Web Application

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

A very common question, but almost all comparison I've seen is mainly focused on games with a lot of interaction.

What I'll be working on is a web application that manipulate objects one at a time. For example, the object can be either an image or a text, then it can be replaced, resized, rotated, zoomed in, and deleted.

If the manipulations applied to many objects, I know that canvas will be a better choice but here the manipulation only can be done one at a time to one object only. Each container will at most have about 30 object in it, and I'll be working on multiple containers (maybe around 20 containers) that will be hidden or shown depends on the interaction.

The question is whether to use Canvas or CSS3? What I'm looking is the performance issue and complexity of the app.

Comment: If you're tracking 30*20=600 objects then I would lean towards canvas because 600 DOM objects will require a good bit of resources whereas 600 canvas objects have less resource overhead.  If you were more in the 100-200 object range I would suggest SVG.  SVG objects are "self-aware" and have the transform capabilities you are looking for (scaling, rotating).

Comment: Ok, will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with canvas but as far as I know if you use it together with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) the performance is pretty similar to CSS animations. You should also consider that CSS animations are very limited when it comes to working with complex animations.